# App Icon Disabled by Theme

Tags: android

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm not finding an answer anywhere.

I'm working through the beginning Android tutorials and my application icon is not showing up, even though I'm positive it is referenced correctly in my manifest file.  What I'm finding online is pointing to the app icon being disabled in my current theme.

How can I forcefully enable it?  This is what I tried to no avail:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/ic_launcher2</item>
</style>
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My OnCreate method is as follows on my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Sorry what dir is what in?  The code snippet I posted was in app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

Comment: I mean the icon image

Comment: It is in all of the drawable folders crated by Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Material Design guidelines, app icon is not recommended anymore on the toolbar. That's why your theme from the support library is disabling it.

Try calling:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

in the `onCreate` method of your `Activity`.

Comment: Could you post your onCreate()?

Comment: I added it to the original post. :)